# delete all files in local path

Tags: c#, visual-studio, delete-file

I need to delete all files in local path of my software except my software

my script :

```
string a = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(a), File.Delete);
```

errors:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: L'accès au chemin d'accès
>   'D:\FWeb\AutoUpdate\AutoUpdate\bin\Debug\AutoUpdate.exe' est refusé.

Comment: You're trying to delete the file that's running...

Comment: There are plenty "delete own executable" questions https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+delete+own+exe - which I'm sure you've already read... But somehow this info on what you've tried did not get into the post....

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to delete a file that's in use - most likely the executable of the current process. You can either skip this specific file, but be aware that if it loads any libraries (.dll files) they may be locked as well. Other files may also be in use (such as .pdb files, resources, etc.) so make sure you exclude everything like that.

```
var assemblyPath = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
var pathsToExclude = new[] { assemblyPath };
string a = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyPath);
foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(a).Except(pathsToExclude))
    File.Delete(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to filter out your own assembly. Of course you cannot delete the binary that is currently running, so exclude it from the list:

```
string location = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
string a = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(location);
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(a).Where(f => f != location).ToArray();
Array.ForEach(files, File.Delete);
```

---

To avoid case-sensitivity problems you may consider

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(a)
                          .Where(f => !f.Equals(location, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                          .ToArray();
```

instead.